# How to find the location of a menuitem within a menu, in coordinates

Tags: java, swt

In Java/SWT, is it possible to find the location of a menu item relative to its parent menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`MenuItemLocator`](http://downloads.instantiations.com/WindowTesterDoc/integration/latest/docs/html/reference/javadoc/com/windowtester/runtime/swt/locator/MenuItemLocator.html).

E.g

```
ui.click(new MenuItemLocator("File/Save"));
```

Comment: I believe I need the whole framework... :) Should have a look at it.